Парсинг ini файла в powershell
Есть ini файлы такого типа (около 200 шт)
[Main]
Port=132
Type=20
[Device]
Host=192.168.1.1
Comments=PC-1

Требуется со всех файлов вывести значения Port, Host и Comments но в формате
Port          Host            Comments
132           192.168.1.1     PC-1
133           192.168.1.2     PC-2

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно это сделать

Что-то типа такого:
$Files = ls <path to folder with files>
Foreach ($ini in $Files) {
     $Obj = [pscustomobject]@{                                                                                                 
         Port     = ($ini | select-string port) -replace "^.+="
         Host     = ($ini | select-string host) -replace "^.+="
         Comments = ($ini | select-string Comments) -replace "^.+="
     }
     if ($Obj) { $Objects += @($Obj) }
     Return $Objects

